# Possible malware files, cannot determine if a threat

Tags: windows-8, virus, malware

During my routine PC cleaning, I noticed a few things that may have been overlooked by MBAM Pro, Windows Defender, and Spybot S&D (all up-to-date, of course). I have never seen them before, on my computer or any other (I have 15 years of computer experience), and I am a little concerned.

I did some Google searching to no avail; my GoogleFu may be weak at the moment.

Here they are:

- `dehxp.exe`
  [image]
- `Adobe148.exe` & `6moxz.exe` (displayed as `New Tec`)
- `Adobe852.exe` & `5f5wt.exe` (displayed as `New Tec`)
- `Adobe512.exe` (displayed as `Thunderbird`)
- `WindowsMediaPlayer.exe` & `uem7r.exe` (displayed as `Setup Installer`)
  [image]

All of these files reside in the `%APPDATA%` directory, which is `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming` on my machine.

I had to turn off the `Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)` option under `View > [Folder] Options > View [tab] > Advanced settings` in order to see the actual exe files.

I also disabled all of them prior to a required reboot after scanning, and `dehxp.exe` re-enabled itself.

Additionally, under `dehxp.exe`'s dropdown, I can only get the properties or show the file location of `dehxp.exe`, both `Explorer` entries just have `Search online` enabled.

I am running Windows 8 Pro x64 (legit) with the latest updates. Also, I have never installed Mozilla Thunderbird on this computer, which is why I have it included on this list, especially since it isn't even `thunderbird.exe`.

Finally, in the bulleted list, any of them in the form of `item1` & `item2` are identical in file size and were created within minutes (usually one minute) of each other.

Has anyone seen any of these before? Should I be concerned?

Thanks!

EDITS AND UPDATES:

1. User [Aaron Miller](https://superuser.com/users/162434/aaron-miller) suggested [using ComboFix](https://superuser.com/a/597791/17104); however at the time of this writing it is **not** compatible with Windows 8, even if you try to install it with Compatibility Mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this specific set of symptoms before, but it sure looks like malware to me. Sounds like [ComboFix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/) time; if anything can get rid of malware, that tool is it, but do read the [guide](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/combofix/) before you run it.

Comment: Alright cool! Thank you your quick response. I was waiting to run that guy actually since in my experience MBAM and SB S&D get 99.5% of all the malware on a machine when run in tandem. As I was unsure of these, for the above reasons AND the icons are weird; facebook and Half Life-esque. I will run it and see if it picks them up, then I will report back!

Comment: Ugh..unfortunately CF will not run on windows 8. If you try to run it in compatibility mode, it also errors out saying it is not meant to run in compatibility mode... :(

Do you happen to know any alternative programs that do similar operations as ComboFix?

Comment: Yikes. Not sure what to suggest, in that case; sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: No worries; I think I may just delete the potentially offensive files and remove them from the startup registry manually, that is if another solution does not present it self. Thanks again though, all input is greatly appreciated!